# Convert Python 3 ResourceWarnings into exception

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to force a Python 3 unittest to fail, rather than simply print a warning to stderr, if it causes any ResourceWarning?

I've tried the following:

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='error', category=ResourceWarning)
```

Which results in this output from unittest:

```
my_test (__main__.MyTest) ... Exception ignored in: <socket.socket fd=9, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketType.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('127.0.0.1', 54065), raddr=('127.0.0.1', 27017)>
ResourceWarning: unclosed <socket.socket fd=9, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketType.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('127.0.0.1', 54065), raddr=('127.0.0.1', 27017)>
ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.110s
```

Note the "Exception ignored" message. I'd rather the test failed, instead of requiring me to read its output looking for ResourceWarnings.

Comment: How about using `warnings.catch_warnings` context manager described in section [29.5.4. Testing Warnings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#testing-warnings)?

Comment: No, I tried that. Daniel Harding showed below why ResourceWarnings are special and can't be detected the normal ways.

Comment: I had read Daniel's answer before posting yet I'm not sure there's nothing more to the subject. Specifically his answer is based on the analysis of `Exception ignored in: (...)` which I believe is the result of using *simplefilter* with `action-'error'` by you. It doesn't mean there couldn't be another way to get hold on warnings, which wouldn't relay on converting them to exceptions thus avoiding unfortunate behavior of `PyErr_WriteUnraisable`.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost - thanks for making me aware of `warnings.catch_warnings`.  That looks like a great way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a unit test that fails if `ResourceWarning` is generated by the code in `with catch_warning()` statement:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import gc
import socket
import unittest
import warnings

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_resource_warning(self):
        s = socket.socket()
        ####s.close() #XXX uncomment to pass the test

        # generate resource warning when s is deleted
        with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as w:
            warnings.resetwarnings() # clear all filters
            warnings.simplefilter('ignore') # ignore all
            warnings.simplefilter('always', ResourceWarning) # add filter
            del s        # remove reference
            gc.collect() # run garbage collection (for pypy3)
            self.assertFalse(w and str(w[-1])) # test fails if there
                                               # are warnings

if __name__=="__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: This looks like a great solution - I was not aware of `warnings.catch_warnings` when I wrote my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, it doesn't appear to be possible.  That "Exception ignored in:" message is produced by the CPython function `PyErr_WriteUnraisable` in `Python/errors.c`.  The comment before that function states:

```
/* Call when an exception has occurred but there is no way for Python
   to handle it.  Examples: exception in __del__ or during GC. */
```

The `ResourceWarning` is indeed being generated during garbage collection, and Python prints a message because it doesn't have a way to raise an exception at that point.  This has to do with the core CPython implementation and there is nothing that unittest can do to override it.

**Update:** while the above is a correct technical analysis, there is another approach that will actually solve the OP's problem.  See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25067818/3573385) by J.F. Sebastian for more details.

Comment: For the sake of context, in case of socket object in Python 3.4.1, `PyErr_WriteUnraisable` is being called at http://hg.python.org/cpython/annotate/c0e311e010fc/Modules/socketmodule.c#l3857 and `PyErr_WriteUnraisable` is defined at http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c0e311e010fc/Python/errors.c#l865